# How to sync files in directory a from directory b?

Tags: bash, find, rsync, ls

I have two folders:

Directory A:

```
- test.txt
- subfolder1/test2.txt
```

Directory B:

```
- test.txt
- test4.txt
- subfolder1/test2.txt
- subfolder1/test3.txt
```

Now, I want to sync the files in `directory A` from `B`, but only the files, which exist in `A`. So, when I change `test4.txt`, nothing should happen, but when I change `subfolder1/test2.txt`, it should be synced.

My approach is following. Get a list of the files in `directory A` with relative path to directory a. Supply it as an argument to rsync relative to `directory B` and sync to `A`. 
Is it right? So I need a bash script? I am not very experienced in bash scripting.

How can I get the relative paths? Have I `cd` into the directory and execute `find *`?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync has an option to only update files without creating new ones. From [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

```
--existing              skip creating new files on receiver
```

Example rsync command for your case:

```
$ rsync -r --existing B/ A/
```